# Is the Eclipse Indigo javascript support useful/usable with jquery?

Tags: jquery, eclipse

I've installed 3.7M6 and the WTP javascript support. It thinks that jquery 1.5.2 has hundreds of errors, making a giant noise in the error window. Is there a way to configure it to get along better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M7 shouldn't indicate as much by default.  jQuery is more dynamic than JSDT can currently figure out, and the lack of any inline documentation doesn't give its inferencing engine anything to work with.  The $ variable's going to be handled better in RC1, but I don't think we'll have resolved all of the issues in time for Indigo.

Answer (score 1):

If you add that js file to the fragments to ignore, it will turn off the 'red'.

window > preferences > general > content types > text > jsp > jsp fragment > add

Then just put the no wild-card file name in there.